# JMH: How to avoid sharing state from abstract base state?

Tags: java, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I'm benchmarking a Spring Boot app startup time. The complete project is [here](https://github.com/asarkar/spring/tree/master/boot-benchmark), which is WIP, but the relevant classes are as below.

Abstract base state:

```
public abstract class BootAbstractState {
    private Process started;

    private boolean isStarted() {
        return Objects.nonNull(started) && started.isAlive();
    }

    protected void start() {
        if (isStarted()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already started");
        } else {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(getCommand());
            try {
                started = pb
                        .inheritIO()
                        .start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void stop() {
        if (isStarted()) {
            try {
                started.destroyForcibly().waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                started = null;
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract String[] getCommand();
}
```

Concrete state:

```
public class JarLauncherBenchmark {

    @Benchmark
    public void benchmark(JarLauncherState state) {
        state.start();
    }

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class JarLauncherState extends BootAbstractState {
        private static final String MAIN_CLASS = "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher";

        @TearDown(Level.Iteration)
        public void tearDown() {
            stop();
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getCommand() {
            return new String[]{"java", "-cp", System.getProperty("java.class.path"), MAIN_CLASS};
        }
    }
}
```

I build a shadow JAR, and run it as follows:

```
java -jar minimal-benchmark/build/libs/minimal-benchmark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-all.jar \
  -bm avgt -f 1 -foe true -i 5 -wi 1 -tu ms
```

The above fails with the following exception:

```
# JMH version: 1.20
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_66, VM 25.66-b17
# VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 1 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
# Benchmark: mypackage.JarLauncherBenchmark.benchmark

# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:00:06
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: <failure>
<failure>

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already started
        at mypackage.BootAbstractState.start(BootAbstractState.java:22)
        at mypackage.JarLauncherBenchmark.benchmark(JarLauncherBenchmark.java:13)
```

Clearly, it doesn't work the way I thought, and a new state isn't instantiated for each iteration. I also tried with `Thread` scope, and running multiple threads (`-t` command line option) but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Iteration" is not "`@Benchmark` invocation" -- which is captured by the tree levels (Trial, Iteration, Invocation) throughout the API. It would be `@Setup(Level.Iteration)` --> `@Benchmark` (several times, until iteration time is expires in `avgt` mode) --> `@TearDown(Level.Iteration)`.  Thus the second invocation of `@Benchmark` would get you the exception like this, because `started()` was indeed called before.

It is usually a bad idea to have unbalanced `@Setup`/`@TearDown` pair. Since you are doing the `@TearDown(Level.Iteration)`, you should really be doing `@Setup(Level.Iteration)`, and do `start()` there.

Comment: 1. Given that my goal is to time the startup, if I move the `start` call to `Setup`, what’d each invocation of benchmark do? 2. What’s the relation between fork and invocation?

Comment: In this case, you want `@TearDown(Level.Invocation)`, with the associated caveats, see the `Level.Invocation` Javadoc. Or, you might want to switch to `BenchmarkMode.SingleShot`, and then each "iteration" would contain exactly one "invocation".

Comment: "Fork" is the execution of the forked JVM, which contains one or more "Trials", which contains one or more "Iterations", which contains one or more "Invocations".

Comment: So, start in setup, stop in tear down, both at iteration level, blank benchmark, run with ss. Did I get your suggestion right?

Comment: If you want to measure `start()`, then `@Benchmark` with `start()`, followed by `@TearDown(Level.Iteration)`, run with 'ss'. Basically, you can run your original example with 'ss'. The cleaner way would be doing `@TearDown(Level.Invocation)`, which would work in any mode.

Comment: Thank you, that seem to be the only way to make it work, although the various warnings on Invocation mode are kind of scary.